# Why my blender will show such an error color in render preview mode?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I don't know why my render preview mode viewport will show such an error color, any kind of helps are appreciating !!!

[image]

Comment: Do you have an AMD GPU?

Comment: Artifacts like those and errors on displaying the interface are likely caused by an unsupported gpu, or an error in the drivers for the gpu. Try updating or downgrading the drivers. For further help [edit] your question and add more information in your system, and what version of blender you are using.

Comment: What OS, GPU and driver are you using?

Comment: Thank you all for replying my post, I have already solved this issue by switching (forcing) my graphics card preference in NVIDIA Control Panel to NVIDIA GTX 1060, ( By default is Intel Integrated Card),  and the error shown in the picture disappeared right away after i restarted blender. It seems like blender is not compatible with my Integrated Graphics Card, ( or maybe blender cannot run on Integrated gpu at all?)   By the way, this error will only show up in Eevee render mode, Cycles is working fine.  My OS is Win10 , driver is game ready downloaded in Geforce experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying my post, I have already solved this issue by switching (forcing) my graphics card preference in NVIDIA Control Panel to NVIDIA GTX 1060, ( By default is Intel Integrated Card), and the error shown in the picture disappeared right away after i restarted blender. It seems like blender is not compatible with my Integrated Graphics Card, ( or maybe blender cannot run on Integrated gpu at all?) By the way, this error will only show up in Eevee render mode, Cycles is working fine.